# Where does this xpath lead to in this XML file (confused on the ancestor part)?

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes, element

This is the XML file:

```
<bib>
    <book> <publisher> Addison-Wesley </publisher>
        <author> Serge Abiteboul </author>
        <author> <first-name> Rick </first-name>
        <last-name> Hull </last-name>
        </author>
        <author> Victor Vianu </author>
        <title> Foundations of Databases </title>
        <year> 1995 </year>
    </book>
    <book price=“55”>
        <publisher> Freeman </publisher>
        <author> Jeffrey D. Ullman </author>
        <title> Principles of Database and Knowledge Base Systems </title>
        <year> 1998 </year>
    </book>
</bib>
```

Based on the XML above, I'm trying to find out: What does the below XPath query look for?

```
– /bib//address[ancestor::book]
```

Does it lead to grandparents of ancestors that have `book`?

In terms of nodes based on the above XML document, when `bib` is the root element, what does ancestor lead to?

Comment: There is no `<address>` node in your XML so the result is empty

Answer (score 2):

It finds all the `<address>` elements that have a `<book>` element as an ancestor.

- `/bib` - Find a `bib` element starting at the root

  - `//address` - Find all the `address` elements that are descendants of that `bib` element

    - `[…]` - but make sure that they are able to match the criteria in the brackets

      - `ancestor::book` - look along the [`ancestor` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/ancestor) for elements named `book`.